# NoClassDefFoundError with Java 8 method reference

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-espresso, android-testing, method-reference

I am running Android instrumentation tests on an emulator on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org). The following test case invokes a [helper method per **method reference**](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/blob/6bc1db863b4cd8c35ce7879281f8c489a759ae82/Umweltzone/src/androidTest/java/de/avpptr/umweltzone/utils/ContentProviderTest.java#L151):

```
@Test
public void testGetLowEmissionZones_worksAtAll() {

    // ...

    lowEmissionZone.childZones.forEach(this::testChildZone);

    // ...

}

private void testChildZone(@NonNull ChildZone childZone) {
    // ...
}
```

When [Travis CI executes](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/builds/494458339#L1502) this test it **fails** with a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
ContentProviderTest > testGetLowEmissionZones_worksAtAll[test(AVD) - 4.3.1] FAILED 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: -$$Lambda$ContentProviderTest$He_xH9TsDaN0tZU8EqFP1CuQyAM
    at ContentProviderTest.testLowEmissionZone(ContentProviderTest.java:151)
```

If I change the method invocation then there is **no** error:

```
@Test
public void testGetLowEmissionZones_worksAtAll() {

    // ...

    for (ChildZone childZone : lowEmissionZone.childZones) {
            testChildZone(childZone);
    }

    // ...

}
```

I tried both **openjdk8** and **oraclejdk8**, both fail.

How can I continue using method references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are facing this issue because `forEach(Consumer<?> consumer)` is not available in Jelly Bean.

As you can see, the test is failling on 4.3.1. Ensure that this is related to API levels of the AVD. Ensure the code is working properly on API level 24 onwards.

Comment: Good point. My understanding was that the [desugar step](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) of the Android toolchain transforms any language constructs back to their counterparts in lower Java versions. Is this not true for `forEach`? - Why do you especially mention API level 24 (7.0) here?

Comment: @JJD `forEach` method has been added in that version.